# why my transition getting delay on return?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using the styled component for transition on my para code as below

```
export const Para = styled.p`
  max-height: ${(props) => (props.collapse ? '3.6em' : '20em')};
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: ${(props) => props.collapse ? 'linear-gradient(to top,#25232363,#ffffffde);' : ''};
  -webkit-background-clip: ${(props) => (props.collapse ? 'text' : '')};
  -webkit-text-fill-color: ${(props) => (props.collapse ? 'transparent' : '')};
  transition: max-height 1.5s linear;
  `
```

It's doing gradient effect if my text truncate height transition getting delay in return okay while expanding & how can I put the transition on gradient effect to not be vanish immediately

Comment: You want to delay the `transition` right?

Comment: it's delaying on return already I don't want any delay

Comment: when height expands that's working fine but on collapse it's doing delay for 2s maybe

Comment: It is hard to say like this... plz add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).